# Is there/what is the best way to query all `img` tags in an Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was wondering if there was a way, or how it would be possible to get an array of all `img` tags in an Angular app? Something along the lines of:

```js
let imgArray = document.querySelectorAll('img');
```

One that queries through all the components and child components.

Comment: You can query only the current DOM

Comment: What you have should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **also** use a directive and ViewChildren. A selector in a directive can be an element of html, so, e.g.

```
import { Directive,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'img' //<---see the selector is all the "img"
})
export class ImgDirective {
  constructor(public elementRef:ElementRef) { }
}
```

So, e.g. you can has a component like

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChildren(ImgDirective) images:QueryList<ImgDirective>
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    console.log(this.images)
    this.images.forEach(x=>{
      console.log(x.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('src'))
    })
  }
}
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hggk3y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: The directive really don't make anything, you can make some more interesting, e.g. you can use HostListener to make some like:

```
  @HostListener("mouseenter") onMouseEnter() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.opacity = 0.5;
  }

  @HostListener("mouseleave") onMouseLeave() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.opacity = 1;
  }
```

**Update** if we inject a simple service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  images:any[]=[]
  constructor() { }

}
```

In the directive:

```
constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef,dataService:DataService) {
    dataService.images.push(this.elementRef)
  }
```

We can has all the imgs

```
console.log(this.dataService.images)
```

But only the images that you has in one moment.

Comment: Thank you! But this would only get me all the Images within that component right? I was wondering in terms of the whole application, as in getting all the images from all the components in the Angular app. Is tha  possible?

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your question :(

Comment: So imagine an Angular App with a few components. Component-1 has three `img` tags, component-2 has one `img` tag, Componenet-3 has five `img` tags and so on. Now, if I want access to all the `img` tags from all the Components, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Because as I understand, the answer you provided only affects the `img` within that component, i.e.  the  `AppComponent`, right?

Comment: Yes, ViewChildren only affect to the Component. well, thinking about this, is we inject in the directive a service that has a public property "images" that was an array, I think that the directive can push the element. I updated the stackblitz

Comment: We can use ngOnDestroy to remove elements from the array